# What is this trigonometric identity equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

Please what are these trigonometric identities
(1) $a \sin A+b\sin B$ in terms of $\sin$
(2) $a \cos A+b\cos B$ in terms of $\cos$?

Answer (score 3):

For (1): Let $B=A+C$ for some $C$, then,
 $$a \sin A+b\sin B=a \sin A+b\sin (A+C)=d\sin(A+D)$$ 
where $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos C}$ and $D=\arctan \frac{b\sin C}{a+b\cos C}$. You can get a similar formula for (2)